# How to ssh login a system with exit profile

Tags: linux, shell

When I add the script snippet "exit 0" in profile, I can not ssh to this linux system any more.
How to fix it.

Comment: Remove "exit 0" ?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

The actual answer is that you can `ssh` to that machine, however when doing an `ssh` it reads your profile where it reads directly `exit 0` so it cleanly terminates your ssh session.

If you do something like :

```
ssh user@machine
```

Then `ssh` will try to invoke a login-shell. Assuming your default shell is `bash`, then you find the following in **`man bash`**:

> When bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a non-interactive shell with the `--login` option, it first reads and executes commands from the file `/etc/profile`, if that file exists.   After  reading  that  file,  it
>          looks for `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, and `~/.profile`, in that order, and reads and executes commands from the first one that exists and is readable.

So since you have an `exit` statement in one of those files, your `ssh` session will terminate immediately.

**how to solve it:** remove the `exit` statement.